# Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 crashes creating or opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was on the process of starting a new WPF application with VS2010 beta 2, and while trying to add some menu items to a window VS hang. I terminated the program and restarted it. However, since then VS2010 crashes every time i try to either open any solution or when i try to create  one. There is no messagebox, nothing, just a beep and then VS crashes.
Has anyone experienced this before? Is there any way to find out if vs writes or logs anything before crashing? This is really annoying. :(

Comment: You should probably report that problem at http://connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar bug reported, only that a (unelpful) dialog box appears when trying to open Visual Studio. The workaround in that case is to reset Visual Studio to its initial state by running it via `devenv /resetuserdata`, maybe this helps in your case too if you can't find a better solution. See here more details: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=499244

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a second copy of VS2010, attaching its debugger to the first copy, and telling the second one to break on all exceptions (Debug, Exceptions).

Then, try again in the first copy, and see if the second copy shows you an exception.  (and tell us what the exception is)